# Analogue of scalar potential in London equation

Tags: condensed-matter, potential, superconductivity

The London Equations to describe superconductivity phenomenologically are:
$$ E = \frac{\partial}{\partial t}(\Lambda J)$$
$$B = -c \nabla \times (\Lambda J)$$
with $\Lambda = m/ne^2$. It is interesting to notice that the quantity $\Lambda J$ plays the role of an effective vector potential above, so it is natural to ask if there is another quantity that plays the role of effective scalar potential in London equation.

It would like great if someone can point me to relevant discussions in books or in the literature.

Comment: A naive guess is that the scalar potential will depend on the charge density $\rho$ with some multiplicative constants.

Comment: A naive guess is that anything but a constant scalar potential $\phi$ would mess up the equations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Including a static scalar potential in London equations doesn't make much sense, since we are talking about the inside of a metal, where any such potential is screened, even in a non-superconducting state. In other words, constant potential is the only option.

**Update**
In a contradiction to what I have written above, the London equations do include the electric field - via the time derivative of the vector potential. However, this electric field cannot be re-expressed in terms of a scalar potential, i.e. *the London equations are not gauge-invariant* - which appears to be a known problem, see, e.g., [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0312619).